# AuraEnabled methods do not support return type of Map<String,Set<String>>

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

This is my Code in apex, But its showing Error-AuraEnabled methods do not support the return type of `Map<String, Set<String>>`

I am not getting what's wrong in my code and why `map<string, set<string>>` not working, while `Map<string, list<string>>` working fine.

```
public class testmap {
    @AuraEnabled
   Public static Map<string,set<string>> getmap() {
        Map<string,set<string>> accountmap=new Map<string,set<string>>();
        set<string> valueset=new set<string>();
        
        valueset.add('Value1');
        accountmap.put('Key1',valueset);
        system.debug('Maptest'+accountmap);
        return accountmap;
   }
}
```

Comment: Aura methods need to be static.

Comment: @PhilW even after making static , same problem exists

Comment: As @phil said make it static and another point is why dont you set return type of the method as  Map<string,set<string>> instead of Map<string,set>. Can you please try this and paste your working method if it dosnt work.

Comment: See this same problem exists:@Arpit


public class testmap {
    @AuraEnabled
   Public static Map<string,set<string>> getmap() {
       Map<string,set<string>> accountmap=new Map<string,set<string>>();
        set<string> valueset=new set<string>();
        
        valueset.add('Value1');
        accountmap.put('Key1',valueset);
        system.debug('Maptest'+accountmap);
        return accountmap;
     

}
}

Comment: Ah, yes, definitely you cannot say "set" without qualifying which type it is a set of.

Comment: @phil any other suggestions apart from that , why its still not working

Comment: looks like Set in retrun is still not supported: https://blog.texei.com/lightning-components-auraenabled-method-parameters-whats-working-and-what-s-not-83c351356104

Comment: @prachi I tried your code and yes it is not supported yet.
As you said list is working fine and you need unique elements. Do one thing here, return list and only add list elements if list.contains method return false or you can create a set and convert it to list before assignment to Map<String, List<String>>

Comment: yes @arpit list, string all are working fine, as mentioned by tushar I think it is not supported

Comment: @Prachi I was editing my comment, can you please go through it now.

Comment: The blog posting Tushar shared earlier in the comments does indicate you cannot use Set, which is interesting.

Comment: Yes, it is Interesting @Phil W, and thanks  Tushar for sharing this useful Blog

Answer (score 3):

This error happens because, somewhere along the way, Set is not supported sent to the client, so rather than break things, they simply don't allow that return type for now. I presume that salesforce.com has walled off this return type until the conversion on the client matches, rather than implicitly converting it to an Array, which could break their plans for a future change when Set is properly supported (imagine your code one day breaks because the client's type changed from Array to Set). The obvious solution, for now, is to return a List instead. You can use a helper method for this:

```
static Map<String, List<String>> convertToMapList(Map<String, Set<String>> source) {
  Map<String, List<String>> result = new Map<String, List<String>>();
  for(String key: source.keySet()) {
    result.put(key, new List<String>(source.get(key)));
  }
  return result;
}
```

This stopgap will allow you to fairly easily switch back to `Map<String, Set<String>>` when/if this data type becomes supported, and also avoids a total rewrite of your code.